# Large file-based bitmap manipulation library

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap

Is there any (preferable open source - but not necessarily) file-based bitmap manipulation library? The basic functionality will include taking a view (a small rectangle) of the bitmap (1-4 GB), changing it and saving it back.

I'm not particularly picky about format (as long as it is lossless): BMP, uncompressed Tiff or Targa will be just fine.

It doesn't have to be all-native code - a wrapper around native dll will be OK although 64-bit version will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Karol, please have a look at it: [ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) is all you need.

Check here for all its [Feature Listing](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/features.html)

Comment: I cannot find any API which allows me to load only part of the bitmap. Can you please elaborate how can I use FreeImage to process 4GB bitmap without loading it completely into memory (which will fail in any system with less than 6GB of RAM).