# Better .NET Bitmap API

Tags: .net, image, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Large file-based bitmap manipulation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053929/large-file-based-bitmap-manipulation-library)

I am trying to generate images from binary data and save them to disk. I'm not really interested in displaying the images, as they will be displayed in other software. So far I know of two free options to create images:

1. [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx), which is a really clunky API in my opinion.
2. [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) which is designed to be used in a WPF environment for displaying generated images.

So far I can't find any better imaging APIs. Are there any better free .NET imaging APIs out there?

Comment: Is the data the image without headers ?

Answer (score 0):

.Net ImageMagick is very powerful,

http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/